# appending a form (HTML) questions (Java Script) to a function

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and I thought I would decide to use some resources I haven't used before. I am stuck on appending a form and questions of my quiz app to javascript?

```js
var score = 0,
   currentQuestion = 0,
   questions = [
  {
    title: 'Who Won Super Bowl I? (1967 Season)',
    answers: ['Packers','Bears','Cheifs','Raiders','Vikings'],
    answer: 0
  }, 

  {
    title: 'Who Won Super Bowl XVII? (1982 Season)',
    answers: ['Cowboys','Cardinals','Redskins','Steelers','49ers'],
    answer: 2
  }, 

  {
    title: 'Who Won Super Bowl XXXIV? (1999 Season)',
    answers: ['Bears','Rams','Patriots','Titans','Seahawks'],
    answer: 1
  },

  { 
    title: 'Who Won Super Bowl XLI? (2006 Season)',
    answers: ['Patriots','Colts','Saints','Ravens','Steelers'],
    answer: 1
  },

  {
    title: 'Who Won Super Bowl XXXVIII (2003 Season)',
    answers: ['Patriots','Panthers','Redskins','Cheifs','Browns'],
    answer: 0
  },

  {
    title: 'Who Won Super Bowl XLVI? (2011 Season)',
    answers: ['Broncos','Saints','Ravens','Giants','Patriots'],
    answer: 3
  },

  {
    title: 'Who Won Super Bowl XX? (1985 Season)',
    answers: ['Bears','Redskins','Cardinals','Vikings','Cheifs'],
    answer: 0
  },

  {
    title: 'Who Won Super Bowl VII? (1973 Season)',
    answers: ['Patriots','Steelers','Dolphins','Vikings','Rams'],
    answer: 2
  },

  {
    title: 'Who Won Super Bowl XXXV? (2000 Season)',
    answers: ['Ravens','Steelers','Bears','Packers','Bills'],
    answer: 0
  },

  {
    title: 'Who Won Super Bowl LII? (2017 Season)',
    answers: ['Eagles','Patriots','Browns','Chargers','Redskins'],
    answer: 0
  }
];

function showQuestion() {
  if (currentQuestion == questions.length) {
    showSummary();
  } else {
    var question = questions[currentQuestion];
    $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
    $('.answers').html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
      $('.answers').append('<li id="' + i + '" class="answer">' + question.answers[i] + '</li>');
    }
    $('.submitanswer').hide();
  }
}

showQuestion();
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="quiz">
    <h2>Question Title</h2>
    <ul class="answers">
    </ul>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Include sample data. Include the libraries you depend on. *Call* your function.

Comment: Please show us what `questions` looks like. What you're doing seems mostly right. You should change the `append` call so you're not treating `question.answers[i]` as HTML, and it would probably make sense to remember the result of `$(".answers")` rather than going back to the DOM each time, but other than that... (The `append` change would be: `.append($("<li>").attr("id", id).addClass("answer").text(question.answers[i]);` though it's not clear why you want an ID on those...) You probably want call to `empty` as well (to remove the previous question's answers).

Comment: I should have said: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]. I've copied your code blocks into a Stack Snippet, added jQuery, and added a call to `showQuestion()` at the end. It works (but see the comment above). What, specifically, is the question?

Comment: Thanks it worked! I look foward to being apart of the community and helping other people as you have helped me.